# Python - Using a binder key to move the entry cursor in tinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I asked a question earlier in which @TigerhawkT3 assisted me, however now that I am implementing what was suggested over a program involving 2 classes I am running into an error. The code I am working with is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class Calc:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.displayentry = StringVar()
        self.display=Entry(parent, textvariable=self.displayentry)
        self.display.pack()
        parent.bind('<Return>', CalculatorLogic.equal_input)

class CalculatorLogic:
    def equal_input(self, event):
        self.display.icursor(END)


root = Tk()
RunGUI=Calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The error I am having with the above code tells me, "TypeError: equal_input() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" when I press the enter key.

Thank you so much for your time and assistance.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the difference between a class and an instance. I would recommend you to read [this tutorial about classes from the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). Moreover, `self` is specific to each class, so defining `self.display` in `Calc` will not make `self.display` available in `CalculatorLogic`, they are not the same `self`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `CalculatorLogic.equal_input`. That method is an instance method, and so must be called on an instance.

The way you do this is for your `Calc` class (or something else...) to create an instance of `CalculatorLogic`. Also, since `equal_input` depends on a widget created in `Calc`, you need to tell that function which instance of `Calc` to use. To do that, pass in `self`:

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.calc = CalculatorLogic(self)
        ...
        parent.bind('<Return>', self.calc.equal_input)
        ...

class CalculatorLogic:
    def __init__(self, calc):
        self.calc = calc

    def equal_input(self, event):
        self.calc.display.icursor(END)
```

Note: this isn't the only way to do this. The concept is correct (`CalculatorLogic` needs a handle to `Calc` and visa versa), but the implementation can differ. For instance, you could have a third "controller" class that creates an instance of each, and is responsible for communicating between them.